Logging an exception before throwing it
In my application, I have a Logger that writes messages about application behavior into a log file. If an exception is about to be thrown, I want it to be logged as well. To achieve this, I'm passing the exception to the Logger, which logs it, and then throws it.
public static class Logger
{
    public static void Add(LogLevels level, string message)
    {
        //...
    }
    
    public static void Add(Exception exception)
    {
        Add(LogLevels.Fatal, exception.Message);
        Add(LogLevels.Fatal, exception.StackTrace);
        throw exception;
    }
}

Passing exception to the Logger enables me to reduce amount of the code when throwing it (current solution):
public static ICad Instance
{
    get
    {
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            Logger.Add(new NullReferenceException("CAD Connector instance requested before running creation procedure"));
        }
        return _instance;
    }
}

Instead of (old solution):
public static ICad Instance
{
    get
    {
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            var ex = new NullReferenceException("CAD Connector instance requested before running creation procedure")
            Logger.Add(LogLevels.Fatal, ex.Message);
            Logger.Add(LogLevels.Fatal, ex.StackTrace);
            throw ex;
        }
        return _instance;
    }
}

As you can see, the first solution is much more concise.
However, the issue is that compiler does not realize that the exception passed to the Logger.Add will be thrown, so in this example it displays Possible null reference return warning on return _instance. It can be suppressed with return _instance!;, but similar issues keep popping up in other places as well where I use Logger.Add instead of directly throwing the exception, sometimes to the point where it won't even compile (for example in switch statements), requiring dirty hacks and suppressing warnings.
These issues can be worked around, but I feel like I'm doing this the wrong way. Can anyone advise, is there a clean solution for this that doesn't require suppressing compiler warnings, but will also allow me to throw exceptions with minimal code, like in my current solution?

According to CA1065: Do not raise exceptions in unexpected locations: Fields don't throw exceptions and neither should properties. If you have a property that throws an exception, consider making it a method.

@Itallmakescents Good advice, thank you. Even though the usage example I provided has this flaw, the question still remains, as my current approach confuses the compiler.

I'd advise against rolling your own logging in the first place. There are very sophisticated logging APIs and implementations in .Net which are widely used and battle-tested. Use them.

Also: this doesn't make sense to me at all. Either log an error or throw an exception. Actually, this indicates some design flaws to me. I am immediately asking myself why a client would even be able to try and use an uninitialized instance of that class? That's a design error.

ArgumentNullException is a reserved exception and should not be explicitly thrown from your own code CA2201

The solution might be "concise" but it's also incorrect: the stack trace on the exception will show where it's thrown from, which in your proposed code is the logger rather than the source of the exception. It's also not clear to the reader of the code that the program will never continue after Add in the same way that the compiler doesn't either and is complaining about it.

Incidentally, have you tested your code? Neither version logs anything for the stack trace, because an exception doesn't populate the stack trace until it's thrown. Normal practice is to log exceptions where they are caught not where they are thrown.

@iakobski thank you for your comments. I haven't tested this properly yet as I am still trying to find a better solution. But yes, I now tested it, and stack trace doesn't get populated. Perhaps you are right, I should log these exceptions where they are caught.

Maybe something like this:
public static class Logger {
    [DoesNotReturn]
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static void LogAndThrow(Exception exception) {
        // get Execution StackTrace (not Unwinding StackTrace)
        Console.WriteLine(new StackTrace(true).ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
        throw exception;
    }
}

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)] is to hide ourselves from the stacktrace. Additionally, we need to get the execution StackTrace up to this point explicitly, as it is otherwise normally populated during the stack unwinding and finalized when the exception is caught (not thrown).
This feels like a bit of an antipattern though as normally we would have exception handlers a bit higher in the stack which will catch exceptions and log them there.

I agree it is definitely an anti-pattern. Also, your use of inlining achieves the purpose of not adding the method to the stack trace, but at a cost. Inlining is good for cases where a method is called often from a few locations, this is the polar opposite: a method designed to be called all over the code, but called very rarely.

@iakobski I think we are in exception territory anyway.

You can consider returning this exception object again, so that you can throw the exception in its original position
public static Exception LogException(Exception exception)
{
    Add(LogLevels.Fatal, exception.Message);
    Add(LogLevels.Fatal, exception.StackTrace);
    return exception;
}

if (_instance == null)
{
    throw Logger.LogException(new NullReferenceException());
}

If you really don't like typing this "throw", you can also annotate the method with DoesNotReturn:
[DoesNotReturn]
public static void Add(Exception exception)
{
    Add(LogLevels.Fatal, exception.Message);
    Add(LogLevels.Fatal, exception.StackTrace);
    throw exception;
}


This suffers the same issues as the original - an Exception does not have a stack trace until it's thrown, so a blank line is logged.
